# Kein Mathe oder Keine Mathe? Kein Chemie oder Keine Chemie?

Tags: usage, pronoun, negation

In school context, which is correct?

> Ich kann **kein** Mathe und ich kann **kein** Chemie.

or

> Ich kann **keine** Mathe und ich kann **keine** Chemie.

or an in-between?

To me "**kein**" sounds just *right* (at least for "Mathe", not too sure about "Chemie") but when I consider grammar rules, not so much any more. I can't find any resource on this except for somebody [claiming in a Q&A site's comments](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/kein-physik-in-der-schule) that "**kein** Mathe" is correct because of abbreviation.

Comment: Fragen können hier übrigens auch auf Deutsch gestellt werden. Ganz nach Vorliebe.

Answer (score 6):

In a school context, talking about subjects (*Fächer*) has its quite peculiar grammar:

> Ich kann kein Mathe.
> Wir haben dieses Jahr kein Erdkunde.
> Kann ich dein Chemie abschreiben? *(meaning e.g. homework)*
> Murat hasst Physik.
> Bist du gut in Latein?
> Ich habe Reli abgewählt.
> Wir haben in Englisch Frau Dimpflmoser.

So your example looks fine to me *in a school context*:

> Ich kann kein Mathe und kein Chemie.

Outside of school and conversations about school, I would try to understand these words in their regular meaning. That way, Chemie, Mathe (an abbreviation for Mathematik), Physik and Erdkunde are obviously female:

> In der Chemie fühle ich mich nicht zuhause.
> Die Mathe, die man für die Quantenmechanik braucht, ist nicht ganz einfach.
> Der erwachsene Murat hasst (die) Physik immer noch.

Comment: Kann ich dein Chemie abschreiben? This sounds so wrong to my ears. What region (and time frame) is/was this used in?

Comment: @infinitezero Agree it sounds wrong, but is nevertheless used by my kids all the time.

Comment: @tofro would you mind to answer the same question from my comment?

Comment: @infinitezero "is used all the time" == "now". Region is South, but I don't really think this is regional.

Comment: You'd probably drop the pronoun (possesivpronomen in that case) so "Kann ich Chemie abschreiben" oder "Kann ich Chemie bei dir abschreiben".

Answer (score -1):

"Mathe" etc. are referring to a school subject. Das Schulfach or Das Unterrichtsfach so gender is neuter.

See also the comments from O.R. Mapper.

Comment: Das ist falsch. Es heißt ja "Mathe", "Chemie" und nicht "Mathefach". Bei einer Wortzusammensetzung entscheidet immer das letzte Glied, bei "Matheunterricht" wäre es maskuin, "Mathematik" ist weiblich usw. Man kann nicht willkürlich eine passende Kategorie wählen, und behaupten, diese sei normativ. Siehe auch der Löwe, die Raubkatze, das Tier.

Comment: @userunknown: Tut man oft genug. "Der Mercedes", "der Opel", "der Golf" - wieso richtet sich hier das Geschlecht nach "der Wagen" und nicht etwa nach "das Auto"? Es ist willkürlich, und eine der Varianten setzt sich aus welchem Grund auch immer eben durch.

Comment: Fahrzeuge sind auch ein spannendes Thema. Der Honda (PKW) vs Die Honda (== Motorrad). Und als Gegenbeispiel zu deinem Golf "die Isetta"

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Die Behauptung, "Der Mercedes" habe sein Geschlecht vom Wort Wagen bekommen, ist reines Gerate - bei nur 3 infrage kommenden Geschlechtern ist es meist leicht, irgendwas zu finden, das das Geschlecht gespendet haben soll - allein es fehlt eine Faktenlage, die überhaupt erst nahelegt, dass solch eine Vererbung durch Oberkategorien stattfindet. Es sprechen im Gegenteil zigtausende Beispiele sehr dagegen. Die Amsel, der Vogel, das Tier - wieviele Beispiele brauchst Du? Der Hammer, das Werkzeug, der Gegenstand, die Sache.

Comment: Die Lilie, der Korbblütler, die Tomate, das Nachtschattengewächs, der Holunder, die Pflanze, die Tanne, der Baum, etc. ad infinitio. Wir hatten das Thema implizit schon bei Ländern, bei Flüssen, bei Autos. Kennst Du irgendein Reglwerk, das behauptet, das Geschlecht von Wörtern sei kategorientreu?

Comment: @userunknown: "Es sprechen im Gegenteil zigtausende Beispiele sehr dagegen." - soweit ich sehe, zählst du nur willkürlich irgendwelche Substantive auf. Den speziellen Fall, um den es hier geht, dass nämlich eine Gruppe von Wörtern, die alle einer bestimmten Kategorie angehören, _alle_ dasselbe Geschlecht erhalten, zum Teil abweichend vom Geschlecht des offenbar zugrundeliegenden Worts (wie z.B. im Fall von "die Mathe(matik)", wovon "das Mathe(matik)" (als Schulfach) abweicht), kann ich bei deinen Beispielen nicht wiederfinden. Insofern ist die Aussagekraft deiner Beispiele eher zweifelhaft.

Comment: Wer sagt denn "das Mathe"? Das sagt eben keiner, daher weiß niemand, was das Geschlecht von "Mathe" ist. "Die Mathe" wäre eine bestimmte Mathematik (hence: der bestimmte Artikel) - "Eine Mathe" wäre irgendeine, es soll aber eine generelle Aversion gegen die ganze Kategorie ausgedrückt werden. Dass es hier um eine Gruppe von Wörtern (Schulfächer, nehme ich an) geht ist jetzt eine Notbehauptung von Dir, von der Du Dir magische Rettung versprichst, ohne sie selbst auf die Probe gestellt zu haben, dabei wäre es so leicht gewesen. "Ich kann kein Mathe" oder "Ich kann Mathe" oder "Ich mag Mathe" …

Comment: … das ist der Sprache ja herzlich wurscht, welchen Aspekt Deines Verhältnisses zu der Sache Du beschreibst. Du kannst ebenso gut "Ich mag Bauchtanz, Grillen, Brasilien, Espresso" sagen, sprich: die verbindende Kategorie ist "Hauptwort", mehr nicht. Wer sagt, dass er Espresso mag, will über Espresso eine generelle Aussage treffen, nicht über einen oder einen bestimmten. Deswegen gibt es keinen Artikel. Im Ggs. zu Deinem Besipiel mit 3 Wörtern a, b, c, die alle der Kategorie K angehören, sind bei mir die Beispiele immer nur eine Kategorie Ki mit der Teilmenge Kj und der Teilteilmenge Kk.

Comment: Und das Geschlecht wechselt bei jedem Übergang von Mente zu Teilmenge. Da brauche ich keine 2 Exemplare in e. gemeinsamen Kategorie für. Schon das erste Exemplar hat eine andere. Also kann es nicht stimmen, dass man bei der Geschlechtsbestimmung in die Elternkategorie schauen muss, also etwa nach Fach (s.), Unterricht (m.) oder Schulstunde (f.).

Answer (score -2):

I assume the omitted part of those words is "der Unterricht". Also "Ich habe heute keinen Mathe(-unterricht)" oder "Ich habe heute kein' Mathe(-unterricht)".

Comment: Before assuming constructs like "kein' ", wouldn't "(das) Fach" be a much more straightforward expansion of the presumed ellipsis?

Comment: Das Mathefach? Das Chemiefach? Doesn't sound right. And to abbreviate keinen to kein'n and because that sounds like kein isn't so far fetched. But I'm open to suggestions. Eitherway it's colloquial language and not necessary good grammar.

Comment: "Das Fach 'Mathe[matik]'", "das Fach 'Chemie'". "Fach" itself being short for "Schulfach" or "Unterrichtsfach", obviously.

Comment: Then it would be "wir haben heute nicht (das Fach) Mathe" not really "wir haben heute kein Mathe".

Comment: I don't think the term has to be expandable in the concrete sentence. IMHO it's sufficient that if you think about school subjects, you think of them as "das Fach 'Mathe'", "das Fach 'Sport'" etc. Based on that, I intuitively perceive "Mathe", "Sport" (in the sense of school subjects) as neuter nouns/names, and then use them like that in arbitrary contexts, such as "Heute habe ich kein Sport, es fällt aus." ...

Comment: ... It's really the same pattern as with other shortenings. "Die [U-Bahn-]Linie U10" is feminine and gets shortened to the equally feminine "die U10", which could be used e.g. in "Da kommt die U10." (referring to a single vehicle), even though the expanded "Da kommt die Linie U10." would sound somewhat off.

Comment: But "die 10" for "die [U-Bahn-Linie] 10" still sounds good. But "Mathe/Sport/etc" don't seem to have any fitting articles in that context. Like "Mathe(-matik)" is feminin but then it would be "keine Mathe" not "kein Mathe". And "das Mathe" doesn't fit either.

Comment: It's true, an article is not normally used with school subjects (maybe because they behave a bit like "names"?). But how about "Heute hatten wir das beste Mathe aller Zeiten, es gab Gummibärchen für jede richtige Lösung!" ? That sounds correct to me and immediately implies (by virtue of the neuter gender for "Mathe") that it's talking about a "Schulfach". Both "Heute hatten wir die beste Mathe ..." (sounds nonsensical, it's not a different system of mathematics that we're talking about) and "Heute hatten wir den besten Mathe ..." (sounds just wrong, but maybe regional?) would not fit IMO.

Comment: But even names would have grammatical genders and respective articles. In your context "das beste Mathe" sounds less wrong than "die beste Mathe" or "der beste "Mathe", but probably "die beste Mathestunde (ever)" would be the preferred choice. It's actually a good question what to use there.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Die 10, die Bahn, die Linie - welche Kategorie ist denn normativ? Das darf man sich einfach aussuchen, oder ist da eine Regel? Ich hatte heute Hase. Hasenrücken. Hasenfleisch. Hasenpfoten. Such Dir was aus! Aber bitte nicht "Ich kann kein Mathefach." Das hieße ja, es gäbe mehrere, die man alle nicht kann. Das gesuchte Substantiv ist übrigens "Mathe", und wäre es eine Abkürzung müsste danach ein Punkt stehen.

Comment: @userunknown: Ja, im Allgemeinen bürgert sich, soweit ich erkennen kann, eine der möglichen Alternativen als am üblichsten ein. Woher hast du denn den Begriff "Mathefach"? Das klingt für mich absolut ungewöhnlich, sagt man das in deiner Region so?

Comment: @haxor789: Yes, "Mathestunde" would be a valid expression, as well. In similar statements like "Dieses Jahr haben wir das beste Mathe ...", other terms like "der Matheunterricht" would be more fitting. Hence, what "das Mathe" stands for varies a bit by context; it is thus not a simple abbreviated word, but IMHO rather a short-hand term for anything related with the school subject.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: "Fach" hast *DU* im ersten Kommentar ins Spiel gebracht. Ich habe das auch noch nicht gehört und war schon länger in verschiedenen Regionen zu Hause, inkl. längerem Kontakt mit Österreichern und Schweizern. Niemand sagt "Wir haben heute kein Mathefach", ergo kann es keine Ellipse dafür sein.

Comment: @userunknown: Bitte zeig mir genau, wo *ich* die Zusammensetzung "Mathefach" (die für mich sehr eigentümlich klingt) ins Spiel gebracht haben soll. Meine Aussage ist, dass im genannten Kontext "Mathe" ein Fach ist und somit selber auch als Neutrum behandelt wird. Man *kann* unter bestimmten Umständen "das Fach Mathe" sagen, aber auch diese sind nicht deckungsgleich mit den Gelegenheiten, wo "das Mathe" üblich wäre; "das Mathefach" ist es meines Wissens nie.

Comment: Dann sind wir ja, was "das Mathefach" betrifft, @O.R.Mapper, einer Meinung. Deine Versuche, über die wahre, jedoch irrelevante Feststellung, dass gelegentlich "das Fach Mathe" gesagt wird, weiterzukommen, bleibt jedoch sinnlos. Manchmal sagt man auch "Matheunterricht", manchmal "Mathestunde" und im Fall 3, wenn man ~stunde sagt, ist es weiblich, im Fall ~unterricht männlich und das Fach ist sächlich, aber das sind dann Unterricht, Stunde und Fach und nicht Mathe. Wir suchen das Geschlecht von Mathe.

Comment: Alles richtig - und meine Beobachtung ist, dass in Bezug auf Schulunterricht nun mal "das Mathe", "das Deutsch" und "das Sport" gesagt wird, aber (meines Wissens) kein Mensch auf die Idee kommen würde, beispielsweise "die Deutsch", "der Mathe" oder "die Sport" zu verwenden. Somit sind all deine Verweise auf "Unterricht" oder "Stunde" korrekt, aber unerheblich, da sich das Geschlecht dieser Wörter offenbar nicht für generelle Fachbezeichnungen durchgesetzt hat. Das neutrale Geschlecht hat es aber offenbar, also kann man wohl nur schauen, ob das nun völlig willkürlich ist, oder ob es einen ...

Comment: ... naheliegenden Zusammenhang mit einem sächlichen Wort gibt. Und siehe da - tatsächlich, den gibt es! "Das Schulfach".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Naja meistens werden Schulfächer doch ohne jeden Artikel verwendet. Also "Haben wir heut Sport?", "Gib mir mal (die) Deutsch(-hausaufgaben)", "Mathe ist ein Arschloch". Während wenn man die wirklichen Wörter verwendet es nunmal "der Sport", "die Mathematik" und "die Chemie" wäre wohingegen ich bei dem Artikel von Deutsch schon wieder ins staucheln käme, vermutlich "die deutsche Sprache" oder "der deutsche Sprachunterricht". Es gibt Konstruktionen wie "Haben wir heut x oder fällt das aus" aber kann man wirklich zeigen das das Neutrum immer passt?

Comment: @haxor789: Das ist aber keine Besonderheit von Schulfächern. "Hochleistungssport liegt mir nicht." und "Ich interessiere mich nicht für Astrologie." sind ganz gewöhnliche deutsche Sätze, die auch keinen Schluss auf das Geschlecht von "der Hochleistungssport" und "die Astrologie" zulassen. Daraus kann man aber doch nicht darauf schließen, dass es eventuell "der Astrologie" oder "die Hochleistungssport" heißt.

Comment: Naja das weglassen von artikeln heißt ja nicht das sie keinen haben, aber bei Schulfächern würde es mir tatsächlich schwer fallen ihnen im Kontext einen zuzuordnen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: "Meine Aussage ist, dass im genannten Kontext "Mathe" ein Fach ist und somit selber auch als Neutrum behandelt wird." Das kann kein gültiges Argument sein, weil ein Löwe, wie gesagt, eine Raubkatze ist, es aber dennoch nicht "die Löwe" heißt, und Raubkatzen sind Raubtiere - in welchem Kontext bitte nicht? - und dennoch heißt es "die Katze", nicht "das Katze". Und wer sagt denn und wann "das Mathe, das Deutsch, das Sport" - das hast Du Dir ausgedacht und meine Gegenbehauptung ist, dass man das eben nicht sagt. Was ohne Evidenz behauptet wurde kann auch ohne Evidenz bestritten werd.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich habe auch nicht behauptet, dass sich das Geschlecht des Wortes "Löwe" nach dem der Kategorie "Raubkatze" richtet, sondern dass offenbar das Geschlecht von jeglichen Schulfächern mit dem Geschlecht der entsprechenden Kategorie "Schulfach" übereinstimmt. Dass der Gebrauch von Unterrichtsfächern als Neutrum ein umgangssprachlicher Regionalismus ist, der dir eventuell nicht bekannt ist, schließe ich nicht aus. Dass ich mir das selber ausgedacht habe, jedoch schon, denn Beispiele finden sich nicht nur in genau der Frage hier ("Ich kann kein Mathe und ich kann kein Chemie."), ...

Comment: ... sondern auch in diversen anderen Quellen, die genau dem vermuteten Kontext von Unterrichtsfächern und Umgangssprache entsprechen, wie z.B. ["sagen, dass das Mathe bei den WiWis echt nicht schwer ist"](https://www.spin.de/forum/494/-/2921); ["Ist das Mathe bei Grundschullehramt bzw. das Studium generell wirklich so schwer?"](https://www.studis-online.de/Fragen-Brett/read.php?101,2212824); ["weil das Chemie in der Schule ja eher weniger auf das Studium vorbereitet"](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/chemie-studium-vorlernen-aehnliches-buch-wie-mortimer-).

Comment: Das Problem ist das "Ich kann kein Mathe" dir nicht sagt ob du "die Mathe", "der Mathe" oder "das Mathe" nicht kannst. Duden positioniert sich ganz klar mit "die Mathe" vermutlich wegen "die Mathematik", aber gut klingt das auch nicht. Und "das Mathe" klingt völlig falsch und das es von Schülern online verwendet wird macht es schwierig. A) Ist das die Hauptzielgruppe dieser umgangsprache also die die es wissen müssten weil sie es benutzen aber B) da haben auch einfach viele keinen Plan von Grammatik und C) wie gesagt wiederspricht massiv jedem Sprachgefühl. Also eventuell regional...

Comment: OK, @O.R.Mapper, Treffen sich 7 Löwenkinder in der Löwenschule. Sagt der eine: "Ich kann kein Hase und kein Schlange" und ein anderes antwortet "Ich kann kein Murmeltier". Das sind alles legitime, wenn auch phantastische Schulfächer. Du meinst es gibt eine Regel für Schulfächer, die aber nur für Schulfächer stimmt, nicht für Tierarten? Ich sage das kann nicht sein. Nicht nur, weil man ein riesiges, enzyklopädisches Wissen bräuchte, für welche Kategorien in welchen Kontexten welche Oberkategorien maßgeblich sind, es bräuchte auch eine Instanz, die diese Maßgeblichkeit festlegt.